# How to detect if full text search is installed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I need to find out if full text search is installed on SQL Server 2005. I don't have permission to log into the box and fire up Setup to check. However I can run SQL Server Management Studio and connect to run queries with sysadmin permissions.

Does anyone know how to detect if this feature is installed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I like `SELECT` over `PRINT`

So here is my take on this

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
         WHEN 
             FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') = 1 
         THEN 
              'INSTALLED' 
         ELSE 
              'NOT INSTALLED' 
    END IsFullTextInstalled
```

Answer (score 26):

```
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) 
    PRINT 'INSTALLED' 
ELSE 
    PRINT 'NOT INSTALLED'
```

(SQL Server 2005)

MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188418(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: FYI - In the event anybody else is wondering, this still works in 2014.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the list of services on the machine.  If full text search is installed you'll see a service named **SQL Server FullText Search ([instance])** where **[instance]** will be the name of the SQL instance that it is associated with.

Comment: I was able to connect to the SQL box through the Services MMC console and found the SQL Server FullText Search service there.

Answer (score -2):

If you have sql server management studio, you should be able to find out following the steps [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403375(SQL.90).aspx). If you find it already checked, then its enabled.

Comment: Hmmm... does that actually tell me if the feature is installed?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.